# How to detect from the client, a connection closed by server using nodejs request library

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, node-request

I am connecting (stream, long lived connection) to a server that get restarted quite often. I am connecting using [http-request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) (nodejs). When the server gets restarted my clients stops, but not gratefully. Not sure on what's the way to detect that the connection was closed by the server.

I'm using:

```
request.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log("Request on error fired: " + err);
    });
```

but doesn't seem to do the trick. Should I listen to the response object instead? The idea is to catch the error and try to reconnect after a while.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```
req.on("close", function() {
  // request closed unexpectedly
});

req.on("end", function() {
  // request ended normally
}):
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Despite the `close` event seems to not be documented.

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/331) states that 'close' event does not work for some cases. You can refer the link. You can overcome this by using websockets...

Comment: The point is that `close` gets fired also if the client stops the _request_ manually using `req.abort()`